# Call custom link in websphere theme

Tags: jsp, portlet, websphere-portal

I have created few hidden pages through Portal Admin and I have mapped the pages using URL mapping. I need to call these hidden pages in my portal theme. I am new to websphere and would need some help.

Comment: What do you mean by Hidden pages? Do you mean the pages which are not visible in the navigation?

Comment: Yes, the pages are not visible in the navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the URL generation APIs to generate URLs to those pages. There are Helper classes for constructing URL provided by IBM. You can find it [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21351642)